# Calling automatic constructor: why is my type incomplete?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, compiler-errors

In the following code, I want to use the default constructor `{.data = value}`, because I want my class to be POD. I don't understand the error message I get on compilation (llvm or gnu, c++11):

```
#include <type_traits>

class a {
  char data;
  static inline a create(char c) { return {.data = c}; } // this fails
  static inline a create2(char c) { a x; x.data = c; return x; } // this is OK
public:
  void init(char c) { *this = create(c); }
};

int main() {
  a s;
  s.init('x');
  return std::is_pod<a>::value;
}
```

with error message

```
t.cc:5:43: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'a'
  static inline a create(char c) { return {.data = c}; }
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
t.cc:3:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: cannot convert
      argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'const a &'
```

Can some kind soul explain to me why the type of a is incomplete when I want to use it, and why it's treated as `void`?

Comment: Designated initializers don't exist before C++20, are you using a compiler extension?

Comment: Why don't you just write a *constructor* (`a(char c) : data(c) { }`) or set of?

Comment: @Quentin: it compiles fine with -std=c++11 on all the systems I tried.

Comment: @Aconcagua: if I put this constructor, my class won't be POD anymore -- and won't be equivalent to a `char` in terms of memory footprint and argument passing.

Comment: @grok "-std=c++11" usually doesn't mean "comply with C++11", but "comply with C++11 plus the enabled language extensions".

Comment: @molbdnilo maybe for Visual Studio, but it does imply certain strictness for GCC/Clang...

Comment: @rubenvb - Not as much strictness as one might think. GCC and Clang really do need a `-pedantic` flags to be really strict.

Comment: @grok Also `std::is_pod` is now deprecated in C++ 20 so I would advice using `std::is_trivial` and `std::is_standard_layout`

Comment: @StoryTeller you mean `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-aliasing -Werror -pedantic-errors`. At least you don't have to pass `/Za` or similar...

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk OP seems to be really asking about C++11, but with compiler extensions.

Comment: Then this is not C++11 either. It is compiler specific.  C++11 tag should be removed in my opinion. And compiler tag added instead.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but member functions that are defined inside the class definition are implicitly inline, so you don't need to mark `create` and `create2` as `inline`.

Comment: You say *"it compiles fine"* and also *"the error message I get on compilation"*. I don't see how both statements can be true at the same time. Does it, or does it not, compile fine? If it compiles, then what's the question? If it fails to compile, then what makes you believe that your compiler supports designated initializers? Far as I can tell, the error message is just the compiler being confused by an unfamiliar syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot aggregate initialize a private member.**

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

> An aggregate is one of the following types: ... class type (typically, struct or union), that has no private or protected non-static data members

Since `a` is a `class`, not a `struct`, `data` is `private`.

Declare `data` to be `public`, or declare the type to be a `struct` to default it to `public`.

Then replace `static inline a create(char c) { return {.data = c}; }`

with `static inline a create(char c) { return a { c }; }`

per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

direct-list-initialization (2)

Comment: Additionally your program as written with my change returns 1 (indicating an error), because true implicitly converts to a 1. Compiled and run with MSVC 14.